# How much money do you have in savings - UK Visitor visa , Could I show mutual funds and Stock market investment as savings?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I was asked to enter "how much money do you have in savings" while I was filling my UK Visa form. I have entered the amount I current have in my Bank Account.

I have also invested in *mutual funds* and *stock market*, could I add those amounts to my bank balance and include it in my savings ?

If the answer to question above is **NO** then :

I can sell shares and redeem my mutual funds and I will receive the amount in my Bank account within 1-2 days ? Could I then show it as my savings ?

I am a salaried person so I can show proofs for funds added to my account by submitting salary slips, but How will I show proofs for the amount credited to my account by selling shares or redeeming mutual funds ?

Please help !

Comment: You can include these within your savings amount, assuming you have paperwork to prove the amounts. Why would you want to suddenly sell shares and redeem mutual funds unless you need the cash to fund your trip? If you do need the cash, you can prove the source of the proceeds into your bank account by providing the paperwork showing your ownership and subsequent sale.

Comment: I am not sure about how much amount would be sufficient to justify to visa officers to grant me the visa. so that's why I thought I could add some money to my bank account by selling some shares

Comment: There is no fixed amount. It depends on your plans for the trip - how long you want to stay, accommodation, personal expenses etc. Being able to demonstrate stable finances, and proportionality of spend to your circumstances is as important as the amount of savings you have. Reading this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab  might help, if you haven’t done so already

Comment: I would have thought that leaving them invested shows you are a person of means who can fund the trip out of income (which is positive) and if they are funds in your home country show an intention to return (also positive).

Comment: @Traveller I have more than double the amount in my bank account saving than I plan to spend on my entire trip, would that be sufficient ? also I was reading about people's experiences of visa refusal due to 'random' deposits in the account ? I once lent some money to my friend ( around 750 GBP) from my bank account and he paid me back within a week to the same account, would this returned money be counted as 'random' deposit in my account? if yes then how should i prove to authorities that it wasn't a random deposit ?